# root.withdraw not working on if statement?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


def get_path():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    path = askdirectory(initialdir="YOUR DIRECTORY PATH")
    root.destroy()


option = int(input("Chose a option:  "))

if option == 1:
    get_path()
```

so basically this doesn't do nothing, but if i just execute the function get_path() (without using the if statement) it does what it is suppose to do (Ask directory while hiddding tk window). Thanks for any help.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: im trying to make so that the filedialog window (to ask which directory the user wants too put certain file) appears without appearing the default tk window by using the root.withdraw() but when i execute that in an if it doesn't appear nothing. But when i do it without using root.withdraw() it works fine but the tk windows appears. (btw this is just an example of code)

Comment: it works fine for me, when inputting `1`

Comment: It works fine for me as well in my Windows 10 running Python 3.9.1.